# Is there a way to replace a piece of string with a logical statement (not, and, or)

Tags: python, python-3.x, logical-operators

So, I've just started learning Python and I got an assignment to make a program that takes a propositional calculus formula and values of X, Y, and Z (True or False) as input. Then it should write if the answer if true or false. Formula should consist of only 3 operations: - (not), & (and), v (or). Variables in the formula should only be X, Y, Z and the all can appear 0 or more times.

---

Examples of possible formulas:

- Y
- -(-(YvX)&Y)
- --X (double negative)
- -Z&Z

Value of variables should be given in binary like this:
 010 (X = f, Y = t, Z = f). For value of variables, I did this

```
value = input("Value: ")

X = value[0]
Y = value[1]
Z = value[2]

if X == "0":
    X = False
elif X = "1":
    X = True
else:
    print("False input")

if Y == "0":
    Y = False
elif Y = "1":
    Y = True
else:
    print("False input")

if Z == "0":
    Z = False
elif Z = "1":
    Z = True
else:
    print("False input")
```

---

Pretty sure that there is a better way to do this but this should still work. The problem is in reading the formula. My idea was to replace the symbols (-,&,v) with not, and, or. Something like this:

```
a = input()
print(a.replace("v", or))
```

But you can't do that, so I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: You can *create a new string* with the change applied (which is in fact what `str.replace` does), but strings are **immutable** so cannot be changed in-place. That said you'll have to replace `"v"` with *the string `"or"`*, not the operator, which isn't an identifier so cannot be used like that.

Comment: Well I think first of all it would be good to know if you're supposed to use Python's eval / code interpreter for this or if it's part of the task to write the formula parser, too. Then you'd have to do all the resolving of associations and prioritization etc. yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like :

```
>>> def interpret(values, formula):
...     X, Y, Z=[int(i) for i in values]
...     newF=formula.replace('-', ' not ').replace('v', ' or ').replace('&', ' and ')
...     return eval(newF)
... 
>>> val = raw_input("Value: ")
Value: 011
>>> form = raw_input("Formule : ")
Formule : -(-(YvX)&Y)
>>> interpret(val, form)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
input_string = "--X&Y"
output_string = []
for elem in input_string:
    if elem in ["-"]:
        elem = "not "
    elif elem in ["&"]:
        elem = " and "
    elif elem in "v":
        elem = "or "
    output_string.append(elem)
print ("".join(output_string))
```

Please note that the replaced "or", "and" and "not" are strings, not logical operators.